# In what year will I be 20000 days old

Tags: php, forms, date

I Have a php script

```
if (isset($_POST['getdays'])) {

    $birthday = $_POST['daysalive'];

    $now = date("Y-m-d");

    $days_alive = date_diff(date_create($birthday), date_create($now));

}
```

Which returns me the amount of days a user lives by echoing:

```
$days_alive->format('%a days old');

<input name="daysalive" type="text" class="mt-3" placeholder="12-12-2018">
<button name="getdays" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Check in what year you will be 20000 days old</button>
```

What I would like to do is take this input and determine in what year the user would be 20000 days old. I was thinking of looping through `$days_alive` using a `for()` loop with an if statement like so:

```
if($days_alive + 365 >= 20000) {
    echo(date('Y');
}
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a `date_add` function which allows you to add a `DateInterval` to a `DateTime` object. So you just need to add a `DateInterval` of 20000 days like so:

```
date_add(date_create($birthday), new DateInterval('P20000D'));
```

Comment: Hey, I have `$days_alive = date_add(date_create($birthday), new DateInterval('P20000D'));` when I try to `echo($days_alive)` it tells me `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in `

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out I did this: `$days = $days_alive->format('Y');` so I get the year only. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for loops. You can use strtotime or DateTime to calculate it.

```
$birthday = "1975-01-01";
$res = strtotime($birthday . " + 20000 days");
echo date("Y-m-d", $res); //2029-10-04
```